# I defined two variable in controller function but I can't access both in view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In controller at return I pass 2 variable with `->with ('',$..)` but I can't access both variable in my view.

```
<table border="1" >
    <tr>
        <td>Total Income {{$balance}} </td>
        <td>Remaining Balance</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Withdrawn {{$result}} </td>
    </tr>
```

I want to access both balance and result but I can't access. The error shows that Undefined variable `balance` .

Comment: Share the return line from your controller.

Comment: I'd use return view('some.view', compact('balance', 'result'));